# I'm trying to filter items from array by accessing a nested property & checking if it property value contains a certain string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

I'm trying to filter an `array` of `objects` by the `summary` nested property, if it includes the word `Save` in the `summary` prop value `string`. This is the `array`:

```
const issues = [{
    id: '1',
    key: 'CLS-1',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Save princess',
      assignee: 'Mario',
    }
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    key: 'CLS-2',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Save Mario',
      assignee: 'Luigi',
    }
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    key: 'CLS-3',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Kidnap princess',
      assignee: 'Bowser',
    }
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    key: 'CLS-3',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Get kidnap!',
      assignee: 'Peach',
    }
  },
]
```

I have tried this one-liner:

```
const getItemsBySummary = items.filter(item => item.fields.includes('Save'));
```

But I get the error `item.fields.includes` is not a function`. I'm guessing because` fields`is an`object`instead of an`array`so it cannot run the method`includes()`. However, I tried like so

```
const getItemsBySummary = items.filter(item => [item.fields].includes('Save'));
```

But I get an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `const getItemsBySummary = items.filter(item => item.fields.summary.match(/Save/));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well since fields is an object , and you want to filtre according to the proptery  summary , you should use this instead :/

```
const getItemsBySummary = items.filter(item => item.fields.summary.includes('Save'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `item.fields.summary` to access the required field.

```js
const items = [{
    id: '1',
    key: 'CLS-1',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Save princess',
      assignee: 'Mario',
    }
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    key: 'CLS-2',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Save Mario',
      assignee: 'Luigi',
    }
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    key: 'CLS-3',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Kidnap princess',
      assignee: 'Bowser',
    }
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    key: 'CLS-3',
    fields: {
      summary: 'Get kidnap!',
      assignee: 'Peach',
    }
  },
]
const res = items.filter(item => item.fields.summary.includes('Save'));
console.log(res);
```